# No persistence provider found with JBoss AS 7

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I've just migrated from Tomcat to JBoss AS 7.
So, I configured Mysql datasource in JBoss (adding module.xml with associated Jar, adding driver bloc into standalone.xml and configuring datasource through JBoss interface.

No errors when deploying but impossible to get an entityManager (JPA with Hibernate in background).

Indeed, when this code is executed:

```
Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("RoomManagement");
```

I obtain this error :

> javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for
>   EntityManager named RoomManagement
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69)
>     javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47)

Very strange because I well verified that my persistence.xml does take place into War at WEB-INF/classes/META-INF directory.

My persistence.xml looks like as follow :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="RoomManagement" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS</jta-data-source>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Address</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Building</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Civility</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.EventType</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Job</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Reservation</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Room</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.RoomType</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Tool</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.User</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.UserDetail</class>
        <class>com.parisdescartes.roommanagement.domain.entities.Schedule</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Did I make a mistake or forgot to specify something ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remove the hibernate jar from `WEB-INF/lib`. JBoss has that bundled, so if you have it on the classpath it probably confuses the classloader.