# JBAS011445: Failed to get adapter for persistence provider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence'

Tags: java, mongodb, jakarta-ee, wildfly, hibernate-ogm

I try to deploy an application what uses hibernate ogm and I always get the error "Failed to get adapter for persistence provider 'org.hibernate.ogm.jpa.HibernateOgmPersistence'".

I have installed the module ogm under WILDFLY_HOME/modules/org/hibernate but it didn't help.

Do I need to configure something in standalone.xml? Does someone have an idea?

Thanks and best regards

Comment: didn't this help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10080004/no-persistence-provider-found-with-jboss-as-7

Comment: No, it didn't help. I don't have hibernate jar in WEB-INF/lib. I tried to remove the used hibernate maven dependencies, but it didn't help too. Thank you anyway for your answer.

Comment: I'm getting the same error deploying to WildFly 8.2 - haven't found a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
By removing the following line from `persistence.xml`, wildfly got convinced to accept the deployment:

```
<property name="jboss.as.jpa.adapterModule" value="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4"/>
```

I also had to remove any property for the transaction provider